# What does it mean that image if formed in front of mirror

Tags: geometric-optics

Today my teacher told me about plain mirror that distance of image formed(inside mirror) is same as distance of object.[image]
And clearly I can understand like the frame of mirror shown here is a door and someone exactly like me is standing away from me.
But when it comes to concave mirror, I don't get it how do I understand that image is formed in front of mirror ?

Answer (score -1):

I think you are very much confuse, first thing you should get clear is, images formed by plane mirror are virtual mean incident rays will never intersect in real world, image formed by concave mirror are real with exception,  when object range between (0,F],(where F is the focal distance and 0 is at pole), real image are inverted, when your teacher said  the image formed in front of mirror, he mean the object and image are on the same side.